# How can I share a swf file that loads another external swf file?

Tags: actionscript-3, load, flash, external

So I wanted to give a demo of my project to someone, but I encounter a problem, Im loading an external swf file, and even if I give him both files, it doesn't work..

What should I do to give a playable demo of my work to someone else, if I load an external swf file at runtime?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading an external swf if you give him both files will work, but of course your code needs to be loading that file from the location where you place it. Can you post your loader code?

Alternatively, are you able to put the swf on a website and send him a link? That may not be an option for your specific situation, but since display over the web in a browser is Flash's primary purpose that's generally the simplest way to send demos.

Comment: This is how I load the file: load(new URLRequest("../resources/assets.swf"));

Comment: Okay, so that file path means go down a level in file system and then into the folder "resources." Is that where you put the local file? If not then you need to adjust the loader code to where you put the file. The simplest would be URLRequest("assets.swf") and just put both swfs in the same directory.